# Cannot use ElasticSearch IP Address as Node URI (does not trust server certificate)

Tags: c#, docker, elasticsearch, logging, serilog

Current setup:
-Elasticsearch & Kibana hosted on an ubuntu server with docker (therefore the Elastics API URI is something like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200 for Elasticsearch and xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:5601 for Kibana)
-C# application run locally on my machine

I have been trying to connect to Elastic's API through my C# Application using Serilog and Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch. I am only successful when I create a proxy tunnel to Elasticsearch using ngrok. Using the proxy tunnel (http**s**://aabbccddee11.ngrok.io for example) I am able to log to Elasticsearch with no problems whatsoever.

If I use the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200 URI, the container logs the following:

> http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel

Certificate:

https://ibb.co/LYvzg8p

This is my current configuration in appsettings.json (ngrok):

```
"Serilog": {    
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" ],    
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",    
    "WriteTo": [       
        {
            "Name": "Elasticsearch",          
            "Args": {             
                     "nodeUris": "https://aabbccddee11.ngrok.io",
                     "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=Basic xxx",      
                     "indexFormat": "someindex-{0:MM.yyyy}",
                     "autoRegisterTemplate": true,             
                     "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": "ESv7",             
                     "typeName": ""
              }       
        }
    ] 
}
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

I tried adding using https on my server's uri but had no luck.

Comment: That looks like a cert created by ElasticSearch itself (self-signed) so is by definition not trustworthy. Get a real certificate for your server. [This](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/issues/144) issue in the github repository shows a way to circumvent security (you shouldn't do that beyond development/testing) but i don't see doing that via the config file. It must be done in code.

Comment: How do I get a real certificate for my server?

Comment: They are for sale on the internet?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you meant to generate one, because some guides suggested that for some reason.